# Выравнивание текста в таблице по верхнему краю.

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! 
В таблице

```
<table>
```

у меня идут две колонки с текстом, правая колонка имеет 5 абзацев, левая только один. При просмотре в браузере левая колонка выравнивает текст по центру колонки. В каждой колонке абзацы заключены в <div>. Конструкция следующего вида:

```
<table>
 <td>
  <div>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></P>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></P>
  </div>
 </td>
</table>
```

Скажите, какими средствами можно сделать выравнивание текста по верхнему краю ячейки? Align="top" для абзаца и для *`<td>`*-ячейки не работают почему то.

Comment: Если это таблица, то желательно придерживаться структуры таблицы, а не пихать `<td/>` в `<table/>`, игнорируя `<tr/>`

Answer (score 1):

Было бы здорово уточнить, что конкретно вам не нравиться и чего хотели бы получить :)

Если выравнивание, то выравнивание по горизонтали или по вертикали?

В любом случае, используя css свойства [vertical-align](http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align) (для вертикали) и [text-align](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-align) (для горизонтали) вы можете добиться желаемого успеха. Например:

```
table {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Если нужна конкретная ячейка, или класс ячеек - уточняйте.